# Height of TikZ Graph with Plus/Minus Tolerance

Tags: tikz-pgf, height, glue

I am attempting to put a TikZ graph in a paper I'm writing and have the height of the graph be a height with a plus/minus tolerance.  An MWE is shown below:

```
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[legend pos=north east,
                xlabel=Number of Elements,
                ylabel=Bending Stress,
                height=0.25\textheight, % add plus/minus tolerance here
                width=\columnwidth
                ]
                \addplot[very thick] coordinates {
                    (2,4.3)
                    (4,2.78)
                    (6,1.96)
                    (10,1.24)
                    (20,0.93)
                    (30,1.04)
                    (56,1.15)
                    (80,1.22)
                    (140,1.54)  
                };

                \legend {Line 1}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{BENDING STRESS VS. OFFSET LENGTH}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Depending on the location of the section header, I'd like to vary the height of the TikZ graph to better make it fit on the page.

I have not been able to find anything that works within the TikZ environment.  For example,

```
height=0.25\textheight plus 0.03\textheight
```

throws an error.

Comment: if I change your line to `height=0.25\textheight+0.03\textheight,` (and your legend to `\legend {Line \#1}`) everything works for me. 
Maybe you should post a complete MWE if it does not work for you.

Comment: @bene, I forgot to remove the `#` from the legend, which would be an obvious cause of error. That wasn't my issue, but thanks for pointing that out. My question is more centered on the `height` issue, which I'll try when I get to the office.

Comment: @bene: I did not try it, but isn't `height=0.25\textheight+0.03\textheight` a fixed length instead of a rubber length?

Comment: IMHO, you can't use rubber lengths within a `tikzpicture`...

Comment: sorry, I did really see, you mean rubber lengths. Forget my comment...

Comment: @PaulGaborit, I was afraid of that.  Is there no way to do something similar to rubber lengths for a `tikzpicture`?